# Index Match Result #Ref

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I don't understand why I am getting the #Ref error while I am using exactly the same formula as follows:

`=INDEX(D2:D82,MATCH(L15,A2:A82,0),MATCH(M13&M14,C2:C82&F2:F82,0))` - this gives me the value I need "FT1"

`=INDEX(D2:D82,MATCH(L15,A2:A82,0),MATCH(N13&N14,C2:C82&F2:F82,0))` - the was supposed to give me the value "WT3" but results #Ref. Similarly the following two formulas give me the #Ref error

`=INDEX(D2:D82,MATCH(L15,A2:A82,0),MATCH(O13&O14,C2:C82&F2:F82,0))`, which was supposed to give me "FT3"

`=INDEX(D2:D82,MATCH(L15,A2:A82,0),MATCH(P13&P14,C2:C82&F2:F82,0))`, which was supposed to give me "WT1"

The source table is:

[image]

The result table is:

[image]

Comment: The #REF error will occur when one of the coordinates supplied to the INDEX function specifies a row or column not included in the range, like `=INDEX(A2:B3, 1, 10)` . Therefore, select one of your MATCH functions in the formula and press F9. This will lead you to know which of them returns which value. The #REF error will also occur if the cell specified by INDEX/MATCH contains such an error itself.

Answer (score 0):

The second part of `INDEX` is for the column, you only need the row.

If you want to match on all 3 columns, i.e. A, C and F, try this.

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$82,MATCH($L15&M$13&M$14, $A$2:$A$82&$C$2:$C$82&$F$2:$F$82,0))
```

If you are using Office 365 you could use the `FILTER` function instead of `INDEX/MATCH`.

```
=FILTER($D$2:$D$82, ($A$2:$A$82=$L15)*($C$2:$C$82=M$13)*($F$2:$F$82=M$14))
```

Comment: This may need to enter the formula as array entry means confirm with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` for non 365 versions of excel.